# Laravel 5.8 cors being blocked even when enabled

Tags: php, laravel

I added this package in my laravel api:

[laravel cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors#laravel)

I added the middleware in my global middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Spatie\Cors\Cors::class,
    ...
];
```

I do this in my `config/cors.php` file:

```
'allow_origins' => [
    'http://localhost',
],
```

Even though I still get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.local/api/request' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Try adding the port `'allow_origins' => ['http://localhost:8080']`

Comment: @RolandStarke I've tried this, same problem :(

Comment: Is the `allow_methods` allowing also the `OPTIONS` method?

Comment: Just try with `'allow_origins' => ['*']` to narrow down the issue.